# Chart control SmartLabelStyle disappear from time to time

Tags: c#, .net, charts, mschart

I have `Chart control` that receives real time data and displays this data on my graph, I also add a label that displays the current value:

```
Series seriesBps;

            if (seriesBps.Points.Count() > 300)
                seriesBps.Points.RemoveAt(0);
            seriesBps.Points.Add(wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001);

            foreach (DataPoint item in chart1.Series[1].Points)
            {
                item.Label = "";
                item.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None;
            }

        chart1.Series[1].LegendText = chart1.Series[1].Name = (wf.BitsPerSecond * 0.000001).ToString("0.##");
        DataPoint Point1 = chart1.Series[1].Points[chart1.Series[1].Points.Count - 1];
        Point1.Label = chart1.Series[1].Name;
        chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Yes;
        chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = false;
        chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.BottomRight;
        chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.CalloutLineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;
```

And this is how it's looks like:

[image]

The problem is that every few seconds when the graphs values changed, the `label` disappears because it's looks like it went out of  the `Chart` bounds:

[image]

Can it be arranged that the `label` will show all the time?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.No
 chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Partial
```

or this to move the labels in left of the datapoint

```
 chart1.Series[1].SmartLabelStyle.MovingDirection = LabelAlignmentStyles.Top Or _ 
                      LabelAlignmentStyles.Left Or LabelAlignmentStyles.Right
```

Comment: The first behave the same, the seconds i didn't understand how to use the OR

Comment: Ok im stumped sorry. The use of `or` is to allow the labels to have choice of `LabelAlignmentStyles` rather than just set to 1 value. This cant be done for all properties but it can for `LabelAlignmentStyles`. I dont think there is a property in `Point.Label` that allows you to change label location,  so it may require the manual drawing of `label` controls and trying to place them near the end of your line

Comment: there is an option to put my label in the right side all the time without moving ?

Comment: I'm not sure, this is what smartlabels do when you set their smart alignment http://i.stack.imgur.com/GRSn8.jpg ... just quickly looking at your second chart it looks as if there might be some blank points at the end of your line since it is shorter than the first. This might mean the `label =""` so thats why you cant see it

Comment: After removed label ="" all the labels remained on the graph and not only one

Comment: no I dont mean remove `label=""` I mean check that the last point is not a blank point or contains no data. You might not be able to apply a label then

Comment: Im not looking at the section of code with `item`. Im guessing that `chart1.Series[1].Points[chart1.Series[1].Points.Count - 1];` is not a plotted point since the line looks shorter than in the top chart. Therefore there is no label to apply so thats you are not seeing a label